# python list.remove is not removing all elements

Tags: python, list

So,
I have a list of random elements `lst1 = [1,"random",67,9,32,7.6,5/2]`
when I loop over it to remove all it's elements ,I Get this Output `['random', 9, 7.6]`

this is what i did :

```
for i in lst1 :
    lst1.remove(i)
print(lst1)
```

**In Second case**
When I do the same with this syntax

```
for i in lst1[:]:
   lst1.remove(i)
```

It removes all elements -> `[]`

Can someone tell me what's really happening in both the cases And why it doesn't  remove all elements in first case

Comment: Apart from this being a duplicate, if you want to remove all elements from the list, which not simply use `lst1 = []`. Unless you have multiple references to the list (in which case, are you sure you can just remove all contents?), this removes the `lst1` assignment and if that was the last reference to it, the old list and its contents will be garbage-collected.

Answer (score -1):

Remove method removes only a first occurrence of the given argument

Try this code

```
lst1.clear()
```

this doesn't require the loop

Comment: This does not answer what op is actually asking